# Run a script inside a content page. ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have a masterpage and content page. And I'm trying to run a java script that needs to be executed on the page loading.
As I am using a master page do not have access to the field 
My doubt is how to run the script within the content page? And where the script has to be? the head of the master page or inside the content page?

Comment: I assume you are referring to a Javascript script, why not use c# or VB?

Comment: What kind of script are you referring to? Javascript? And what kind of field are you referring to? More deetails needed, and code examples would help too.

Answer (score 0):

You can run C#/VB code on page load at any page or custom user control, so you will have access to whatever on the page.

I think you want to put that code in masterpage to standardize the procedure, one of the solutions (I don't know if you can accomblish this):

you can build your own "CustomPage" class by inheriting from "Page"
so, you can set the onLoadEvent to a preset action.

and inherit from it for all your pages.

Answer (score 0):

You could put a ContentPlaceholder in the Head section of your master page.  Thats if you want to put your script in the Head